# excessively verbose queries generated by hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

**How can I set up JPQL and/or hibernate to return only a manageable amount of data from an entity that has a complicated web of nested properties?**  Specifically, this query:

```
@Override
public Patient findPatientByHjid(Long hjid){
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT patient FROM Patient patient WHERE patient.hjid =:id");
    query.setParameter("id", hjid);
    return (Patient) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

is generating excessively long hibernate sql.  I have reviewed the program flow in the debugger many times, and I see that it generates the same two hibernate sql statements every time, even though I cannot see why it would generate more than one SQL statement.  The second statement is so verbose that it throws the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join
```

To keep this posting a readable length, I have uploaded some verbose resources to a file sharing site.  **Please note that the file sharing site center justifies the text even though it is right justified in eclipse.**  You can read the two hibernate queries resulting from the above JPQL [by clicking on the following link](https://jumpshare.com/v/zTtkxoZc9wNLDDF5IOSg?b=w0qdqWgRtfm41i7BsjFI).  In addition, you can read the entire stack trace [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/ilCdBR9VJwDRMdserOHb?b=w0qdqWgRtfm41i7BsjFI).  And you can read the code for the `Patient.java` class [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/4GUrfX2MNzoldHDP12x7?b=w0qdqWgRtfm41i7BsjFI).

**How can I change my code so that I only get the small amount of summary data from the query, and thus avoid all these silly extensive unnecessary joins?**

Comment: @fabienbk I did post the code for the `Patient` class in the linked file sharing site in my OP above.  If you click on the link, you will see that it is 1376 lines long, which is way too long to include directly in the posting.  What other entitie files would you like me to add to the file sharing site?

Comment: All those CASCADE_ALL could be a problem, I am not sure right now. If you can use the JPA 2.1 you can pass an entity graph telling the JPA what he should load. Other approach would be using NativeQuery.

Comment: @uaiHebert Thank you.  What would either the `entitygraph` approach or the `nativequery` approach look like in code in this situation? If let's say I wanted to pick only four specific properties of `Patient` that would be returned when `Patient` is queried?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2014/04/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-2-define.html it shows how EntityGraphs works. About the native query, it will only return what you have written in the query.

Comment: @uaiHebert I am using `JPA 2.1` with `java 6`.  Do I need to upgrade to `Java 7` in order to use `entitygraph`?  Eclipse is telling me: `The method createEntityGraph(Class<SomeClass>) is undefined for the type EntityManager`

Comment: @uaiHebert I just set the project `jdk` to `1.7` in `eclipse`, but it is still giving the same compile error.  It does not give me any choices for which package to import, so I don't really know how to get `eclipse` to treat `entitygraph` as a valid type.

Comment: JDK has not to do with it. Check you JPA API version and if your implementation supports it.

Comment: @uaiHebert I changed to newer versions of `jpa`, `hibernate`, and `spring`.  But the error is persisting.  Since those changes make it a different question, I posted the next step as a different question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599436/the-method-createentitygraphclass-is-undefined-for-the-type-entitymanager

Comment: question has no meaning (now) since you didn't include the entity class in the question (and its link is now broken).

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you have tons of EAGER `@ManyToOne` associations. Switch them to `LAZY` because [`EAGER` fetching is a code smell](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).